# Do action on mouseover using Javascript (else if)

Tags: javascript, mouseover, onmouseover

I'm new to Javascript and I'm trying to write some code that will change the text in a specified div when some text is hovered over.

I've written a function that activates onmouseover and changes the text using getElementById.innerHTML

It looks like this:

```js
function changePhase() {
  document.getElementById("phases").innerHTML = "Phase 1 Phase 1 Phase 1";
}
```

```html
<div id="phases">yada yada yada yada yada yada</div>

<p class="hoverhand" id="title1" onmouseover="changePhase()">PHASE 1</p>
<p class="hoverhand" id="title2" onmouseover="changePhase()">PHASE 2</p>
<p class="hoverhand" id="title3" onmouseover="changePhase()">PHASE 3</p>
<p class="hoverhand" id="title4" onmouseover="changePhase()">PHASE 4</p>
<p class="hoverhand" id="title5" onmouseover="changePhase()">PHASE 5</p>
```

I also have a heap more titles that I'd like to do the same thing.

```
<p class="hoverhand" id="title2" onmouseover="changePhase()">PHASE 2</p>
<p class="hoverhand" id="title3" onmouseover="changePhase()">PHASE 3</p>
<p class="hoverhand" id="title4" onmouseover="changePhase()">PHASE 4</p>
<p class="hoverhand" id="title5" onmouseover="changePhase()">PHASE 5</p>
```

What I'd like to do is use the same function with an IF statement to change the text depending on which id is being hovered over. (or use another method if there's a better way)

E.g. If I hover over #title2 the #phases div displays"Phase 2 Phase 2 Phase 2".

else if

If I hover over #title3 the #phases div displays "Phase 3 Phase 3 Phase 3" and so on.

[Here's my JS fiddle so far](https://jsfiddle.net/4durL08q/10/)

I'm looking for a solution in Javascript rather than Jquery please.

Thanks!

Comment: have you need mouse leave event ? open this one https://jsfiddle.net/AhirHasmukh/4durL08q/15/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) to reference the element being hovered. Here is a simple example.

```js
function changePhase(obj) {
  document.getElementById("phases").innerHTML = "You hovered " + obj.innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<div id="phases">yada yada yada yada yada yada</div>

<p class="hoverhand" id="title1" onmouseover="changePhase(this)">PHASE 1</p>
<p class="hoverhand" id="title2" onmouseover="changePhase(this)">PHASE 2</p>
<p class="hoverhand" id="title3" onmouseover="changePhase(this)">PHASE 3</p>
<p class="hoverhand" id="title4" onmouseover="changePhase(this)">PHASE 4</p>
<p class="hoverhand" id="title5" onmouseover="changePhase(this)">PHASE 5</p>
```

**Updated solution based on User's comment:**

```js
function changePhase(obj) {
  var txt = "";

  switch (obj.id) {
    case "title1":
      txt = "Apple";
      break;
    case "title2":
      txt = "Banana";
      break;
    case "title3":
      txt = "Mango";
      break;
    case "title4":
      txt = "Orange";
      break;
    case "title5":
      txt = "Grapes";
      break;
  }

  document.getElementById("phases").innerHTML = txt;
}
```

```html
<div id="phases">yada yada yada yada yada yada</div>

<p class="hoverhand" id="title1" onmouseover="changePhase(this)">PHASE 1</p>
<p class="hoverhand" id="title2" onmouseover="changePhase(this)">PHASE 2</p>
<p class="hoverhand" id="title3" onmouseover="changePhase(this)">PHASE 3</p>
<p class="hoverhand" id="title4" onmouseover="changePhase(this)">PHASE 4</p>
<p class="hoverhand" id="title5" onmouseover="changePhase(this)">PHASE 5</p>
```

**P.S:** [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) provides better performance than `if...else`

Comment: Hi,

I see what you've done here but it's not what I'm after. To clarify: I want to have a completely different message appear for each hover. E.g. One might read "apples" and another "bananas" etc. 

Thanks for teaching me something about using (this) though!

Comment: @AndrewBloyce please check my fiddle link

Comment: Thanks so much @Pugazh . This works just the way I want it to.

Comment: @AndrewBloyce : Welcome. Happy to help :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `event.target.id` to get the element that is triggering the event:

```
function changePhase(){

 var x = "";
 switch(event.target.id){

   case "title1":
   x = "Title1";
   break;

   case "title2":
   x = "Title2";
   break;

   default: //you would follow the same logic used for the first two cases
   x = "Default";

  }
   document.getElementById("phases").innerHTML = x;
}
```

This considers your initial requirement of a conditional statement being present to dictate what the `innerHTML` is.

See the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/pehggpfk/1/

I would say that @Pugazh solution is cleaner and easier to maintain though.

Comment: Perfect. This solution works well for me because I need a completely different set of text for each hover rather than referencing the hovered element. Now I'm off to study why this method works :P.